# Differentiating Between Visual Studio Versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I need to figure out which version of Visual Studio 2008 is installed on particular computers.

Is there a way I can differentiate between Visual Studio Team System 2008 vs Visual Studio 2008 Development Edition?

Are there particular files installed for one that are not installed for the other?

To Clarify my question, I would like to differentiate between:

- Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition
- Visual Studio Team System 2008 Architecture Edition
- Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition
- Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition
- Visual Studio Team System 2008 Test Edition
- Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite

Comment: Where is your code running? as a VS Package, Addin, or just an external program?

Comment: I'm confused, what code are you talking about? I personally have the Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite installed on my machine, and any code I write, I can debug, add to source control and release if necessary.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Because if the code is ran from inside Visual Studio itself as an extension, there are some ways. From your answer, I suppose it's compiled as an external app (an .exe) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the registry would be your best bet. I've found the following key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\InstalledProducts

Under this there's a key for each product installed:

- Crystal Reports
- ...
- Microsoft Silverlight Projects
- ...
- Team Explorer
- Team System - Database Edition
- ...

I don't know whether there's enough there to go on to uniquely identify each version, but it might get you most of the way there.

Comment: Sure, that will differentiate between the 2005/2008/2010 versions. But to clarify my question, I would like to differentiate between say Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition and Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite

Comment: @user290141 - Sorry, I thought you wanted to know the major version as well. I'm still looking for anything that will distinguish the minor versions.

Comment: @user290141 - I've found a key which *might* give you more information.